# R Compare rows in the same dataset by ID to find out if one comes before one

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code that group the data by Id and compare each observation to find out if a value in the column comes after the other. If one comes after the other in a specific order, the observation is slice to show Yes or NO.

This is my dataset:

```
ID  Initial Review      Type
P40 Yes                 Meeting1
P40         Yes         Meeting2
P42 Yes                 Meeting1
P42 Yes                 Meeting1
P43 Yes                 Meeting1
P43         Yes         Meeting2
P44 Yes                 Meeting1
P44 Yes                 Meeting1
```

This is what i want to achieve:

```
ID  Outcome 
P40 Yes     
P42 No  
P43 Yes 
P44 No
```

This code is not doing what I want it to do. Sorry, I am new with R

```
tt %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(outcome = ifelse(Type == "Meeting1" & Type == "Meeting2", "Yes", "No")) %>% select(ID, outcome)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'Meeting1' and 'Meeting2' are the unique values in the 'Type' column, after grouping by 'ID', check the length of unique elements (`n_distinct`) to be equal to 2, if so, return the flag as 'Yes' or else 'No'

```
tt %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[(n_distinct(Type) == 2) + 1])
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  ID    Outcome
#  <chr> <chr>  
#1 P40   Yes    
#2 P42   No     
#3 P43   Yes    
#4 P44   No
```

---

If there are other valuess in 'Type' as well, we can specify the values with `%in%`

```
tt %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[all(c("Meeting1", "Meeting2") %in% Type) + 1])
```

#### data

```
tt <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P42", "P42", "P43", "P43", 
"P44", "P44"), Initial = c("Yes", "", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "", 
"Yes", "Yes"), Review = c("", "Yes", "", "", "", "Yes", "", ""
), Type = c("Meeting1", "Meeting2", "Meeting1", "Meeting1", "Meeting1", 
"Meeting2", "Meeting1", "Meeting1")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Where did you add 1 to the summarise?

Comment: @NartRazak  Sorry, I meant 2.  Changed the wordings

Comment: @ akrun, sorry to bother on this line why did you add 1: c("No", "Yes")[all(c("Investigation", "Conference") %in% EventType)+1]

Comment: @NartRazak  No problem.  iNote that the output of `%in%` or `==` is logical TRUE/FALSE.  which will be encoded as 1/0.  Indexing in R starts from 1.  So, if we change it to 2/1, then we can replace those with a vector of other values in the same order.  here, we use `c("No", "Yes")` so that "Yes" replace the 2 and "No" the first based on the order of values here